# python selenium при использовании кастомной директории вылетает ошибка

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

На данном ресурсе нашел код который меняет директорию профиля, менять директорию меняет но код после долгого раздумья завершается ошибкой, подскажите как исправить

```
path = "D:\programs\Chrome\App\Chrome64\chromedriver.exe"
profile_path = "user-data-dir=D:\\programs\\Chrome\\Data\\Chrome\\Default"
cookie = {'name': 'mid', 'value': 'Vt_MdgAEAAHmiuQaEEjpP01XilYo', 'domain': 'www.instagram.com', 'path': '/'}
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument(profile_path) #Path to your chrome profile

w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, chrome_options=options)
```

вот код ошибки

```
  File "D:\programs_for_dev\environment\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 67, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "D:\programs_for_dev\environment\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 87, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "D:\programs_for_dev\environment\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 141, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "D:\programs_for_dev\environment\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\programs_for_dev\environment\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot parse capability: chromeOptions
from unknown error: cannot parse args
from unknown error: each argument must be a string
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64)
```

Comment: Попробуйте поменять: profile_path = "D:\\programs\\Chrome\\Data\\Chrome\\Default"